# Collection to associative array with specific keys [L5.2]

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-5

I have the next collection:

```
Collection {#356 ▼
  #items: array:31 [▼
    0 => {#359 ▼
      +"id": 17
      +"zone_id": 2
      +"name_de": "Österreich"
      +"name_en": "Austria"
      +"name_iso": "AUSTRIA"
      +"tld": "at"
      +"iso3166": "AT"
      +"phone": 43
      +"vat_regex": "/^U[0-9]{8}$/"
      +"shop_id": 17
      +"country_id": 165
    }
    1 => {#360 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"zone_id": 2
      +"name_de": "Belgien"
      +"name_en": "Belgium"
      +"name_iso": "BELGIUM"
      +"tld": "be"
      +"iso3166": "BE"
      +"phone": 32
      +"vat_regex": "/^[01][0-9]{9}$/"
      +"shop_id": 17
      +"country_id": 25
    }]
}
```

And I want to get the next result as associative array:

```
[
    "AT" => "Austria",
    "BE" => "Belgium"
]
```

I'm trying to do it using:

```
$keyed = $countries->map(function ($item) {
     return [$item->iso3166 => $item->name_en];
});
```

But I'm getting:

```
Collection {#357 ▼
  #items: array:31 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "AT" => "Austria"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "BE" => "Belgium"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I'm doing wrong or how can I achieve the associative array?

*Note: I'm using Laravel 5.2 so **mapWithKeys()** Collection method is not implemented.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use function [`->pluck('name_en', 'iso3166')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck).

Comment: Easy as this, I didn't know about pluck method. Thank you.

Comment: @Troyer yes, collections are really neat; also there is a free book on collections https://leanpub.com/laravelcollectionsunraveled have fun! :)